# Finding unknown function $f(y)$ from $\int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 -1}} = \frac{d}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals

I was doing some underwater geometric acoustics (like geometric optics) and this equation popped up from my calculations.

My question is how do I find unknown function $f(y)$ (which represents underwater sound profile, where $y$ is depth) if $y_{max}$ is solution to $f(y_{max}) = \frac{f(0)}{\cos(\alpha)}$. We also know values $D$ for all corresponding angles $\alpha \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

$$\int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 -1}} = \frac{D}{2}$$

---

I explored the suggestion in the comment and tried to take $\frac{d}{dy}$ on both sides and solve for $f(y)$ and I get the following:

$$0 = \frac{d}{dy}\int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 -1}} = \int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{\left[\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 -1 \right]^{1/2}} = \int_0^{y_{max}} \frac{\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 \frac{1}{f(y)}}{\left[\left(\frac{f(0)}{f(y)\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2 -1 \right]^{3/2}}dy$$

This whole thing is equal to zero because $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{D}{2} = 0$. **But I am still unable to find $f(y)$.**

Comment: Take $\frac d{dy}$ on both sides and solve for $f(y)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I tried you suggestion but still failed (failed attempt can be seen in the question above). Any other ideas?